# error: expected ', ' or ' ;' before 'namespace'

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm very new to C++ and I have no clue why but whenever I try to run my program I get the following error:

```
error: expected ', ' or ' ;' before 'namespace'
```

I'm pretty sure the `using namespace std;` line in the below file is causing the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Helper.h"
#include "KeyConstants.h"
#include "Base64.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MSG Msg;

    while(GetMessage (&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It also opens a file called `stl_construct.h` and tells me the error is from `namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)` in that file. I'm pretty sure this isn't the problem but just in case I'll add some of it.

Excerpt from `stl_construct.h`:

```
#ifndef _STL_CONSTRUCT_H
#define _STL_CONSTRUCT_H 1

#include <new>
#include <bits/move.h>
#include <ext/alloc_traits.h>

namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

/**
* Constructs an object in existing memory by invoking an allocated
* object's constructor with an initializer.
*/
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  template<typename _T1, typename... _Args>
    inline void
    _Construct(_T1* __p, _Args&&... __args)
    { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
#else
  template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
    inline void
    _Construct(_T1* __p, const _T2& __value)
    {
      // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // 402. wrong new expression in [some_]allocator::construct
      ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(__value);
    }
#endif
```

Base64.h

```
#ifndef BASE64_H
#define BASE64_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace Base64
{
    std::string base64_encode(const std::string &);

    const std::string &SALT1 = "LM::&&jARLZ_E5?u ;f9+,4AZwA8MF3t(t+T+   {o!g,Ze22Pu&6$GbROk-* LzIxb?d'";
    const std::string &SALT2 = "'hytO|-h0,Rb@6Z{iH=H=+Q:E{+Y:&<rzP!^;oIC!.OGk5o6)^S^1-o,UcLt(`kQx'?";
    const std::string &SALT3 = "FU%^L,RHo({KD~[iZ/7Y%EehTkaE6^jwYQXwR#5Qh|c?)m?CGC(j-&oG~laZclg?Q'!";


    std::string EncryptB64(std::string s)
    {
        s = SALT1 + s + SALT3 + SALT2;
        s = base64_encode(s);
        s.insert(15, SALT1);
        s += SALT3;
        s = base64_encode(s);
        s = SALT3 + SALT1 + SALT2;
        s = base64_encode(s);
        s.insert(7, "t");
        s.insert(1, SALT3);
        return s;
    }

    const std::string &BASE64_CODES = "ABCDEGFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    std::string base64_encode(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::string ret;
        int val = 0;
        int bits = -6;
        const unsigned int b63 = 0x3F;

    for(const auto &c : s)
    {
        val = (val << 8) + c;
        bits += 8;
        while(bits >= 0)
        {
            ret.push_back(BASE64_CODES[(val >> bits) & b63]);
            bits -= 6;
        }
    }

    if(bits > -6)
        ret.push_back(BASE64_CODES[((val << 8) >> (bits + 8)) & b63]);

    while(ret.size()%4)
        ret.push_back('=');

    return ret;
    }
}

#endif // BASE_64
```

Comment: What is the contents of the other files (`Helper.h`, `KeyConstants.h`, `Base64.h`)?

Comment: The error could be in the header files

Comment: I predict there's a problem at the end of `Base64.h` - a missing semicolon probably.

Comment: Try compiling the header files on there own. i.e. rename them with the .cpp extension and compile them,

Comment: I added "Base64.h" so you could look at it

Comment: It is not in "base64.h" - I copied the code - pasted it to ideone.com. Compiled ok. Try doing that with the other two header files

Comment: I tried KeyConstants.h and it through an error but I don't know if you can pass compiler flags on the website or it won't compile correctly. Here's the link http://ideone.com/YwsqRS The required flags are `-std=c++11` & `-mwindows`

Comment: Nevermind I forgot to add a semi-colon at the end of KeyConstants.h

Answer (score 0):

Check the "KeyConstants.h" file. Don't forget the ";" at the end of the map. (The one tha has the list of keys)

Answer (score -1):

Your missing a semi-colon
Probably at the end of `Base64.h` or `ext/alloc_traits.h` or one of the other .h files like `KeyConstants.h`

Comment: Good answer stating the obvious

Comment: I added "Base64.h" so you could look at it

Comment: Why did you downvote, guys? Such question, such answer.

Comment: Should be a comment and not a answer

Comment: Should be neither. Simple questions like this should be removed when resolved. The error was just syntax, and so these are unlikely to help someone in the future, which is a reason for removal. Even so, simple answers don't belong in the comments because the comments aren't the place for answers.